# Trouble creating php script

Tags: php

For example my website is: site.com and it meta redirects to other url. Now I need a php script which could take any url as input and return this url in plain text format: site.com/?url=url-inputed
I'm just a beginner in php so I am having trouble creating such script Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append the inputed url to previous one then

```
$URI = "site.com/url=$yourURI";
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand, but are you asking how to echo back user input and append something to it?

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
if(isset($input)){
      echo "site.com./?url=url-'. $input .'";
   }
```

Comment: Well I'm gonna use my own website as 3rd party shortener in dlvr.it but actually I'll be meta redirecting the url without creating short links. So I need code that can take url=input and echo site.com/?url=input in plain text